# Strange way to configure IP on Server with Hyper-V. We're doing something wrong?

Tags: networking, ip-address, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

Scenario (real with address/names altered):

Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V installed.

Originally, there were 2 machines let's call them FileServer and MainServer. The FileServer does a little more that just file serving. MainServer have the MSSQL.
When arrived the new shiny server, was decided that they need the FileServer machine
to other uses.

Since the 2008 came with Hyper-V, we tried it. It works, but the way the new MainServer machine got configured that's a little weird (at least for someones accostumed to VMWare not touching physical devices ip configuration).

The original network config:

- FileServer machine (originally physical)

> IP: x.y.z.6 (invented)
>   Netmask:255.255.240.0
>   GateWay: 10.1.35.1

- MainServer machine (physical)

> IP: x.y.z.4 (invented)
>   Netmask: 255.255.240.0
>   GateWay: 10.1.35.1

It ended like this (it's weird, but we could not make it work another way) when the servers above where changed to an shiny new server with 4 physical network adapters:

- FileServer machine (now virtual guest)

> IP:  x.y.z.6 (invented)
>   Netmask: 255.255.240.0
>   GateWay: 10.1.35.1

- MainServer host machine

*Local connection 6 (Hyper-V virtual adapter)*

> IP: x.y.z.4 (invented)
>   Netmask: 255.255.240.0
>   GateWay: 10.1.35.1

*Local connection 4 (physical adapter which is configured on Hyper-V)*

> IP: nothing ( if you run ipconfig you get an address at the 169.*.*.* range)
>   Netmask: 255.255.240.0
>   GateWay: 10.1.35.1

If I put the x.y.z.6 address on the hyper-v adapter and the x.y.z.4 on the physical adapter it points to in Hyper-V it refuses to work. But people keep asking me why such an strange configuration. And the only answers I have to them is: works that way.

My experience is some with the old VMWare Server and VMWare Workstation. I feel that something wrong happened in this, but have no clue of what. Searches here brought no enlightenging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very confusing, but I'll answer based on the assumption that you're mixing between network cards on your host server.

Assume that you have a physical host of 1 network card, When you install hyper-v and configure it with an external network switch, Windows will create a virtual switch and a virtual network card, both will be bonded to your physical network card.

Your host server IP address will be moved from the physical network card to the virtual one so  to enable communication between virtual clients, the host and the external network. What your seeing (that the host network card have no IPs) is normal, you should add the IP to the virtual network card on the host, not the virtual.

If what I'm saying is very confusing too you, then I would suggest to take a read on this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/151.hyper-v-virtual-networking-survival-guide.aspx

once this is covered, your virtual machines should be able to communicate with the host and the external network normally.

Let me know if this is the case or not.

Thanks,